# Rails: Validate uniqueness with a scope coming from another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am not sure how to express this properly so here is the data structure:
In my Rails 6 application, I have a model actor and a model aka (for "also known as" - as some actors have different names at times).

Both models have first and last names. What I want to do is ensure I do not store the same "aka" for an actor twice, however in theory, it should be possible that two actors have the same aka.
Example: Actor "John Doe" might be known also as "Joe Doe" (aka). Actor "Jon Doe" might also be known as "Joe Doe".
So while I want to ensure I don't have "Joe Doe" as aka for "John Doe" - I want to ensure that it is possible to have two "Joe Doe"'s - once for "John Doe" and once for "Jon Doe".

So far, my validation for aka is:

```
....
validates :first_name, presence: true
validates :first_name, uniqueness: { scope: :last_name }

belongs_to :actor
....
```

What do I need to add as a validation to reflect above dependency?

Comment: `uniqueness: { scope: [:last_name, :actor_id]}` will validate that the same first name does not exist with the same last name for the same actor. (Would have to be repeated for last name); however this would be better suited for a custom validation where you can check both at the same time e.g. `if Aka.where(first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name, actor_id: actor_id).exists? #add errors`

Comment: I think you really just need to start by understanding what `validates_uniqueness` actually does. Its a method defined by ActiveRecord (not ActiveModel like the otehr validations) that checks if a record exists with something like a `EXISTS 1 WHERE column_name = ?` query. When you use the scope option you're just adding more AND conditions to the query. `EXISTS 1 WHERE column_name = $1 AND other_column = $2` .

Comment: Also from a real world standpoint the requirement makes no sense. Actors with the same name is very much a thing that exists (like for example all the Sr and Jr examples) and why shouldn't your application allow it? If your making an assumption that a persons name is some sort of unique identifier the world is really going to let you down - and you may be adding a bunch of culturally insensitive assumptions to your application that are going to be problematic like for example that everyone uses the order firstname lastname.

Comment: If you really want to do this and do a uniqueness validation with complex logic like `WHERE a = ? AND (b = ? OR c = ?) ` you really need a custom validation method. But remember that this also needs to be backed up on the database level with constraints if you want to avoid potential race conditions and actually guarentee uniqueness.

Comment: @max thank you - good comments and you are right. I thought a bit more on that and in the real world, this probably doesn't make sense - the name is not a unique identifier. So I actually started to think differently about the whole thing. The community in StackOverflow is just amazing! (like your thought too though engineersmnky - thanks for that too!)